# What are the options for animating a camera sequence with 3D Max files?

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max

I am working with a freelancer to produce some 3D models of our products.  He has been sending me renderings which for the most part is fine, but I'd now like to receive a model that I can rotate around in a scene or more accurately, rotate the camera around.  I don't have nor am I willing to purchase a 3D max license.  I'm looking for a free 3D viewer - no editing capabilities needed.  I just need to orbit the camera.

The CAD world as the [STP format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_10303-21) and it's plethora of [free viewers](http://stpviewer.com/) available.  I looked into 3D Max to STP and it doesn't sound like a promising option due to the nature of the model construction methods.

What would you suggest I use to accomplish my goal?  I did some googling but it's all a little over my head.  I'm hoping you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the opensource solution for 3D modeling is [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) but it is a heavy learning curve in regards to animating but animating a camera sequence isn't very complicated.  If this is for a one time event you could go to 3DS Max's site and receive a free [30 day trial](https://www.autodesk.com/products/3ds-max/free-trial) and follow a couple of video tutorials such as:

- [3DS Max Camera Animation Basic Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmnSeTGRYf4)
- [3DS Max 2013 Tutorial | Animate a Camera on a Path | InfiniteSkills](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2z3b6wU9jyg)
- [08 3ds Max Design 2014 - Basic Camera Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEPK4llpwOU)

A keynote from my experience with 3DS Max back in 2010 is that you cannot open a newer version of a file in a later program without issues.  Example: If he is sending you 2013 `.max` files they may not be opened in a 2010 3DS Max application, this however is my experience with 3DS Max 2008 and 2010 when I was creating animations but it may be different now or they may have allowed this feature in 2013/2014. So if this option is what you intend I would make sure to whoever is doing your modeling is using 2014 because the trial version should be 2014.

If you intend to try your hand at Blender you can go by a few articles on importing a 3DS Max file into Blender:

- [Importing From 3DS Max?](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128062817/https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8595)
- [Importing Autodesk 3DSMAX .MAX files into Blender 2.62](https://forum.unity.com/threads/importing-autodesk-3dsmax-max-files-into-blender-2-62.126844/)
- [Importing Blender Objects To Max](https://wiki.openuru.org/index.php?title=Importing_Blender_Objects_To_Max)

Also, as Scott has stated you could import it in Photoshop extended.  Examples below:

- [How to import 3D files into Photoshop - Cinema 4D/3D Max](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zr5qodhGyk)
- [How to Import a File From 3DX Max to Photoshop](https://itstillworks.com/convert-max-obj-8734383.html)
- [How to import Photoshop Logo into 3ds Max](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GESxYSUZaI0)

And finally you could do this in After Effects:

- [how to import 3ds max model in after effects.wmv](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyx41EJ0BAk)
- [After Effects / Preparing and importing 3D image files](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/preparing-importing-3d-image-files.html)
- [How to import 3Ds Max project into Adobe After Effects CS4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zDZIwWqWmY)

---

This may be off-topic but I don't understand why, if he is sending you renderings, you will not have him create the animations for you.  If he is talented and knowledgeable enough to create quality renderings you are wanting to use why not prevent the headache of trying to figure it out for yourself?

Furthermore, check your contract because there is a difference in receiving the renderings and the original files.  You may have to pay extra to receive the `.max` files.